# Could not load file or assembly Microsoft.SqlServer.management.sdk.sfc version 11.0.0.0 in 2017 server

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio

I have tried everything regarding this issue,i had visited microsoft website to install the required two files but i am missing **** shared managementobjects.msi **** is there any other way to connect to database [i am getting an error while connecting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kGTYp.png)

Answer (score 0):

Install this package using nuget management and check package version should be same in webconfig file.

Comment: bro you have mentioned this package in the statement but you have not mentioned which package to install please mention it #user2042214